# Bootstrap website not working on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-safari

This is the website [click](https://upworkweb.000webhostapp.com) it's work perfect on my side and i test it on responsive device check and all pages work fine but client said it's not work at there specially photo page. 
Can some one please check on iphone and tell me why it's not working;

Comment: Can you share the images?

Comment: actually it's work fine for me but client said it's not working so i want some one to check  is it working or not